# homeomorphic neighborhoods but no homeomorphic open neighborhoods?

Tags: general-topology

Could someone come up with a (continuous) map $f\colon X\to Y$ of topological spaces, and a point $x\in X$ such that the following two conditions hold:

- There exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $f(V)$ is a neighborhood of $f(x)$, and $f|_V\colon V\to f(V)$ is a homeomorphism;
- There does not exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U)$ is open in $Y$, and $f|_U\colon U\to f(U)$ is a homeomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and in fact if the first condition holds, then the second one does too.

Let $V \subset X$ be a neighborhood of $x$ and $f(V)$ be a neighborhood of $f(x)$.

Then there exists $U \subset V$ open in $X$ containing $x$ and $W \subset f(V)$ open in $Y$ containing $f(x)$.

Since $f(U)$ is open in $f(V)$, we have $f(U)= U' \cap f(V)$ for some $U' \subset Y$ open. Now consider $W \cap U' \subset f(V)$. This is open in $Y$ and $f|_V^{-1}(W \cap U') \cong W \cap U'$, so we need to show that

$$f|_V^{-1}(W \cap U') = f^{-1}(W \cap U') \cap V$$

is open in $X$. But if $y \in f|_V^{-1}(W \cap U') \cap V$, then  $y \in V$ and $f(y) \in W \cap U' \subset f(V) \cap U' = f(U)$, so by injectivity of $f$ on $V$ we get $y \in U$. Thus,

$$f|_V^{-1}(W \cap U') = f^{-1}(W \cap U') \cap U,$$

which is open in $X$, and contains $x$.

Comment: Yes, I found the same solution after typing my question. Thanks!